# Issue with a Makefile where one subdirectory isn't getting compiled

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I find that in this Makefile, the EventProducers subdirectory is just not getting compiled although it is similiar in every respect with the other subdirectories. It was added newly. Any reason why the Makefile wouldn't compile this specific folder. Make clean and make has been tried already.

```
include $(ROOTDIR)/$(PROJECT)/abc/defines.mk
include $(ROOTDIR)/$(PROJECT)/def/xyz/delta/defines.mk

local = alpha/Services/Recording

subdirs = Factory EventProducers Search Control Control Serial

INCLUDE_DIRS += -I$(ALPHA_HOME)/Services/Recording

LOCAL_OBXS = \
        $(addprefix $(localobx)/, \
        RecordingBase.o \
        )

LIBS := $(libdir)/libalpha_recording.a
$(LIBS): $(LOCAL_OBXS)

include $(ROOTDIR)/$(PROJECT)/Build/rules.mk
```

Comment: What are the contents of `rules.mk`?

Comment: @NathanPierson - Just other generic things. nothing suspicious there.

Comment: I ask because as far as I can tell there's nothing in this that uses the `subdirs` variable at all. For all I know it's being ignored entirely and some other mechanism in `rules.mk` is what's responsible for actually compiling those contents which is why the other folders work.